# jQuery GoogleMap Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, google-maps

I tried to  use google maps, it works with Chrome IE but not with FireFox?

I miss something :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
function initialize() {

    var latitude = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
    var longitude = document.getElementById("Longitude").value;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var options = { zoom: 16, center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
        ("map_canvas"), options);
    var image = '@Url.Content("~/Images/pushpin.png")';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        title: "Position",
        icon: image

    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}

$(function () {
    initialize();

});
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;margin-top:15px;">
```

Comment: This looks correct to me. What is your `map_canvas` css? Also, does it generate anything in FF (partial map or grayed out map space?)

Comment: My map_canvas is a simple div 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;margin-top:15px;">

Comment: hmm.. Usually the issue is that height and width weren't specified. What happens if you remove the markers? does it work in FF?

Comment: Even when I remove the marker, it is the same issue. the div is here but the map is not

Comment: If you have firebug try to call `initialize` in that console and see if it loads then. I had a very similar problem to this a while ago. I was making a map with multiple markers and it errored out. What fixed it for me was setting all bounds at once and all markers after the map was created, but I don't think this is your issue.

Comment: If it loads the second time, then the issue is your doing to much to the map in to many different places. In that case make sure the map is set to the right bounds `var latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); latLngBounds.extend(latlng) map.fitBounds(latLngBounds );` I don't know if this will help, but everything else you have looks correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery call looks suspicious. I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 initialize();
});
```

On mine I just stuck with the nasty old inline onload="initialize()". If you want a working example you can see what I have [here](http://todoseventos.heroku.com/javascripts/map.js).

Comment: Nothing "suspicious" there, `$(function() { })` and `$(document).ready(function() { })` are exactly identical. Also going back to adding `onload` attributes is not an improvement.

Comment: The onload was not really intended as a suggestion, more of a admission. I hadn't see that shorthand for document ready. Neat. Still the link provided may help.